# Solution of a second order non linear ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ordinary differential equation
$$ \frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}} = \alpha \sinh{y},~~ y = \beta~~\text{along}~x=-\frac{1}{2},x=\frac{1}{2}~~\text{and}~~\frac{dy}{dx}=0~~\text{along}~x=0.$$

Here $\alpha, \beta$ are constants. Is there any standard method to solve these types of ODEs or we need to solve it by hit and trial method. Any help to solve this ODE will be appreciated.

Comment: It is not very clear to me. What means *along* ? Is it *for* ? Do you face a problem with $\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}} = \alpha \sinh(y)$ ?

Answer (score 5):

A fun trick I've seen for autonomous (i.e., no $x$-dependence) second order ODEs (ignoring the boundary conditions for now) is the following: define a new function $u(y) = \frac{dy}{dx}$. Then use the Chain Rule to remark that
$$
\frac{du}{dy} = \frac{dx}{dy}\cdot\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{1}{u}\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{1}{u}\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}.
$$
Your particular ODE now becomes
$$
u\frac{du}{dy} = \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \alpha \sinh(y),
$$
which may be solved by simple integration:
$$
\alpha\cosh(y) + k_1 = \int\alpha\sinh(y)dy = \int u du = \frac{u^2}{2}
$$
where $k_1$ is a constant. Now we can substitute for $u$ and return to the $y(x)$ regime:
$$
\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 = 2\alpha\cosh(y) + k_2.
$$
From here, the problem is just a separable first-order ODE. You could actually eliminate $k_2$ by using your $\frac{dy}{dx}$ condition, yielding
$$
\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 = 2\alpha\left[\cosh(y) - \cosh(y(0))\right].
$$
See if you can solve it from here.

Comment: Simpler could be to multiply both sides by $2 y'$ and integrate both sides for the same result (for sure). Cheers :-)