How do you actually solve a linear homogeneous differential equation rigorously without splitting the differential
I want to solve the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=y$, but I only know the informal way of doing it by splitting the differential.
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y$$
$$\frac{1}{y}dy=dx$$
$$\int\frac{1}{y}dy=\int dx$$
$$\ln|y|=x+C$$
$$y=Ce^x$$
I know that this is the correct answer because exponential functions are their own derivatives. However, this is not the correct way to do it, because $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is not a fraction, but an operator on $y$ instead. When I try to instead try to take the integral with respect to $x$, I get
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}dx=ydx$$
$$\int\frac{d}{dx}(y)dx=\int ydx$$
$$y=yx+C$$
I know that this is not the correct answer, because taking the derivative does not give back the original differential equation. Which step is incorrect? Is it the way that I am setting up the integral, my integration of the derivative of $y$, or is it integrating $y$ with respect to $x$?
If the last option of my integration of $y$ on the right side being incorrect, why is that? Shouldn't this integral with respect to $x$ "consider" $y$ to be a constant?
How is this done the formal way?

You are doing the below manipulation:
$$
\int ydx = yx+C
$$
This is not correct because $y$ is not a constant with respect to $x$, $y$ is a function of $x$. For example, let's say $y=x^2$. Then, the above equation implies:
$$
\int x^2 dx = x^2\cdot x+C=x^3+C
$$
which is clearly not correct, since the antiderivative of $x^2$ is $x^3/3+C$.
Ultimately, the reason "splitting the differential" works is because of $u$-substitution. I think showing how $u$-substitution applies in this situation more explicitly will clarify:
$$
\begin{align*}
& \frac{dy}{dx}=y \\
\implies & \frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}=1 \\
\implies & \int \frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}dx=\int dx
\end{align*}
$$
On the left-hand side, we have $\frac{dy}{dx}dx$. By $u$-substitution, we can replace this with just $dy$, so we get:
$$
\int \frac{1}{y}dy=\int dx
$$
and this is exactly the equation we would have ended up with if we had split the differential before taking the integral with respect to $dx$.
Whenever we "split the differential," we are essentially using $dy$ as a shorthand for $\frac{dy}{dx}dx$, and then when we integrate, replacing $dy$ with $\frac{dy}{dx}dx$ is justified because of $u$-substitution, which is why the approach of splitting the differential has a rigorous basis.

Thank you, this really explains how this works! Is the chain rule applicable for higher order differential equations? My Calculus course hasn't gotten to higher order differential equations, so I am wondering how the chain rule applies when $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$$ is involved.

@Alteria Solving higher-order differential equations can be very tricky and I've only solved higher-order differential equations where the coefficients on the $dy/dx, d^2y/dx^2$, etc. were constant, so I didn't need to separate the differential. However, the same principle of chain rule applies: If we let $u=dy/dx$, then for example, we could apply chain rule in this manner:
$$
\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\implies du=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}dx
$$
This is also a good post to read: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4602231/307483 It applies chain rule in a higher-order DE to the fraction $du/dy$.

The question has already been answered by @NobleMushtak. Just to put it there, here is another "right" way to write these arguments.
Step 1: Use the informal calculation to find the solution, in this case $y=Ce^x$.
Step 2: Express the constant in terms of everything else, and call it a new function. In this case, define $\phi(x)=ye^{-x}$.
Step 3: Differentiate the function, it must be constant, and so you are done. In this case,
$$\phi^\prime(x)=y^\prime e^{-x}-ye^{-x}=(y^\prime-y)e^{-x}=0$$
and so $\phi(x)=C$, or $y=Ce^x$.

Try this:
$\frac{dy}{dx}=y$
$\frac{dy}{dx}\times\frac{dx}{dy}=y\times\frac{dx}{dy}$
$1=y\times\frac{dx}{dy}$
$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{y}$
$x+C=\log_{e}{y}$
$y=e^{x+C}=A\times e^{x}$
Does that work better?
The $\frac{dy}{dx}\times\frac{dx}{dy}=1$ I believe is justified by the chain rule.

This does answer my question, thank you! But what do you mean that dy/dx * dx/dy is justified by the chain rule? Does this approach work for other differential equations as well?

@Alteria Chain rule for derivatives says that:
$$\frac{du}{dv}\cdot \frac{dv}{dw}=\frac{du}{dw}$$ If we use $u=y$, $v=x$, and $w=y$, then we get $$\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot \frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{dx}{dx}=1$$

The chain rule uses limits to prove it is a valid rule for well-behaved functions but once proved, it says (to a non-Mathematician) that multiplication of derivatives behaves a lot like the multiplication of fractions. Hence the product of the two derivatives should be equal to 1.

Right, I had forgotten about that. I'm only in my Calculus 1 course and I only remember the chain rule being used for composed functions. i.e the derivative of f(g(x)) being f'(g(x))g'(x)

How does $\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dy}=\frac{1}{y}$ implies that $x+C=\ln y$ as in your 4th and 5th line ? Isn't that exactly the question OP asked ?

Integrate both sides with y as the dummy variable.

$y' = y$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$
$y'e^x=ye^x$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$
$\frac{y'e^x-ye^x}{e^{2x}}=0$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$
notice that $\frac{y'e^x-ye^x}{e^{2x}}$ is just the derivative of $\frac{y}{e^{x}}$ so:
$\frac{y}{e^{x}}+c_1=c_2$ for some reals $c_1$ and $c_2$ (notice that $e^x$ is non-zero for any real)
$y=ce^x$ for some real $c=c_2-c_1$
notice that every line is equivalent to its predecessor. Rigorously solving these is just about introducing the exp() function in the right way and avoiding the division over a function that is not defined to be non-zero, imo

Where did the denominator for $\frac{y'e^x-ye^x}{e^{2x}}=0$ come from? The step before this should've given $y'e^x-ye^x=0$, right?

@Alteria yeah substract $ye^x$ from both sides then divide both by $e^{2x}$ which is a non zero quantity for any real $x$. 0 divided stays 0 any way,
